# A bit yet to go

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I use the phrase "**A bit yet to go**" saying about a small distance yet left to cover, let's say, by riding a horse or driving a car? The phrase fits into lyrics I'm trying to write. I've searched on Google, but the results seem to mean "yet more things to do" or something like that.

Comment: It's a lyric -- you can use anything you want.  What you suggest is easily understood by native English speakers (at least in the US).

Comment: The very first "hit" when Googling `define bit` comes up with this:  A small piece, part, or quantity of something.
‘give the duck a bit of bread’ / (a bit) A short time or distance. ‘I fell asleep for a bit’

Comment: Thanks! So, I will use it in that context

Comment: I think 'a bit yet to go' is an elegant use of the words that take just the meaning you intend. Keep it up till you get there.